# Multiplying values from a textbox in Yii

Tags: yii

I'm new to [Yii](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yii), and I'm trying to compute values from textboxes. I want the computation codes to be on the same form where the textbox is being displayed (since the product will also be shown on a textbox of the same form where they will input the factors). I've tried this guess, but it didn't work. How do I fix this problem?

```
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'Quantity_In_Pieces'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'Quantity_In_Pieces',array('Quantity_In_Pieces' => ('Quantity').val() * ('Hold').val());?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'Quantity_In_Pieces'); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiplying values from a textbox in Yii Framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10253715/multiplying-values-from-a-textbox-in-yii-framework)

Answer (score 0):

seems like you are trying to write jQuery where there should be php code.

```
<?php echo $form->textField($model,'Quantity_In_Pieces',array('Quantity_In_Pieces' => $model->quantity * $model->hold);?>
```