# Multiplying values from a textbox in Yii Framework

Tags: yii

i'm new to Yii and I'm trying to compute values from textboxes. I want the computation codes to be on the same form where the textbox is being displayed (since the product will also be shown on a textbox of the same form where they will input the factors). I've tried this guess, but it didn't work. How do I fix this problem?

```
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'Quantity_In_Pieces'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'Quantity_In_Pieces',array('Quantity_In_Pieces' => ('Quantity').val() * ('Hold').val());?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'Quantity_In_Pieces'); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiplying values from a textbox in Yii](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10253354/multiplying-values-from-a-textbox-in-yii)

Answer (score 2):

As i understood, you need to add the textField on your ActiveForm and to set its value calculated from two another textfields. In this case you should use [Chtml::textfield(...)](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#textField-detail) with value = ($model->Quantity) * ($model->Hold). I mean smth like

`echo Chtml::textField('Quantity_In_Pieces', ($model->Quantity) * ($model->Hold));`